# Regular expression: close most match

Tags: python, regex

I have a text which looks like:

```
data="""
XYZ
sometext1
...
XYZ
sometext2
...
TPoint
sometext3
...
XYZ
sometext4
...
TPoint
"""
```

I want to extract `sometext2 ...` text between close-most `XYZ` and `TPoint`.

My first attempt was

```
m = re.search("XYZ(.*?)TPoint", data, re.DOTALL)
print m.group(1)
```

but this gives

```
sometext1
...
XYZ
sometext2
...
```

How can I extract

```
sometext2
...
```

?

**I can do some post-processing to extract the part that I want (like rfind('XYZ')), but wonder if there is a way to code it using regular expressions alone**

(if you are interested in the real data: I have a log file, `TPoint` corresponds to some sort of exception and `XYZ` corresponds to a message of interest; so I'm trying to link messages to exceptions. First `XYZ` value in `data` did not result into an exception, but second and third one did)

Comment: why `sometext4...` is not a match?

Comment: `re.search` returns first match only

Comment: basically, do you want to form groups of all `XYZ...Tpoint` that dont have an `XYZ` in between, i.e. message-exception groups ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, ***My Bad!!***
let this be here.

```
XYZ([^XYZ]*?)TPoint //doesnt work
```

---

```
XYZ(((?!XYZ).)*?)TPoint //works


result = re.findall("XYZ(((?!XYZ).)*?)TPoint", data)

for x in result:
   print x
```

Output:

```
"sometext2
...",  
"sometext4
..."
```

See here: http://regex101.com/r/zC8iW7/6

Comment: This means none of the data inbetween XYZ and TPoint can be X,Y, or Z. I.e. it doesn't match `XYZ` followed by `You should match this sentence`.

Comment: No, not together. It doesn't match *any* of those characters, in any sequence, in any word.

Comment: Yes, this won't work correctly if second XYZ is replaced with X Y Z

Comment: @sunbabaphu, to see my point, insert the sentence "You should match this" in between `XYZ` and `TPoint`

Comment: `[^XYZ]` means cannot be characters X or Y or Z

Comment: why this check is three in your regex. look the demo that I shared you.

Comment: Because for the anything above there would be character X in between

Comment: @Braj, for you case the answer should be: `sometext2 XYX ...`

Comment: but its not matching it. Simply replace `sometext2` with `sometext2X`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
reobj = re.compile("(XYZ(.*?))+?TPoint", re.DOTALL)
for match in reobj.finditer(subject):
    print (match.group(2))

#or 
(reobj.finditer(subject).next()).group(2)
```

The first match will contain the text.

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/lSXsnc) and [another](http://regex101.com/r/zL5nQ9/1).

Comment: As per the pattern that is used in your demo, It will not work as shown in [demo](http://regex101.com/r/zC8iW7/7). Simply replace `sometext2` with `sometext2X`

Comment: @Braj The second link was just a bad paste, I've updated the second link now. First one was OK though...

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

In re module there are patterns that use lookahead and look behind assertions...

(?<=...) looks behind

```
examplePattern =  "(?<=XYZ)." #Pattern that matches the first character after XYZ
```

(?=...) looks ahead

```
a =  re.search("(?<=XYZ)((?!XYZ).)*?(?=TPoint)",data,re.S).group()# returns desired output
```

Comment: So how to use it in this case?

Comment: @sunbabaphu should be given credit for the answer which I added to my own.  He uses a negative lookahead to make the pattern explicit in the regex ((?!XYZ).)*?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider not using regular expressions at all, like this:

```
firstTPOINT = data.find('TPOINT')
lastXYZ = data.rfind('XYZ', 0, firstTPOINT)
captured = data[lastXYZ - len('XYZ'):firstTPOINT]
```

It could be made prettier, I'm sure, but the general idea is there.  Find the location of the first 'TPOINT', look backwards from there to find the previous 'XYZ', then use those two indexes to take a slice of the string.

Comment: This sample is a simplified version of the actual problem. Without regular expressions parsing would become nasty. And learning something new about regular expressions is as useful as getting the actual problem solved :)